# Invalid character encountered error - selecting rows

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to get rows from table using SQLDeveloper by writing simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM agreements WHERE agreementkey = 1;
SELECT * FROM agreements WHERE agreementkey = 4;
```

but getting invalid character encountered error. **It's not a problem with query**(working using other keys, i.e. agreementkey = 3) but with XMLType column in this table - there is something wrong with data in some rows. Is there a way to select this affected row(I know keys of this affected rows) using queries? Maybe export to file or something? Solution of copying value manually is not acceptable.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word (as is `table`).

Comment: It was just an example. Query looks different and it's good for 100%(working with other keys).

Comment: @mleko Please provide the correct query ?

Comment: Is `agreements` a view? What datatype is `agreementkey`? And what is the **exact** error message you get? (ORA-xxxxx?)

Comment: No,  it's not a view. Datatype is NUMBER(38, 0). As I wrote in description - it is not a problem with query. This table contains XMLType column and this is the reason - there is something wrong with data and I need to find a way to somehow select this row using query.

Comment: does it  mean you don't get the error when you ddont select all column? so `SELECT agreementkey  FROM agreements WHERE agreementkey = 1;` does not throw the error?

Comment: do you get the error if you do a `create table testtable as select * from agreements where agreementkey = 1`?

Comment: What us the exact error message and what is the database version?

Comment: SELECT agreementkey FROM agreements WHERE agreementkey = 1; throws an error. during select * there is no error because only 50rows are fetched by first time etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty copy of the table and then run an INSERT into it based on a select from the original table but do it using the DML error logging clause.

This should show you any rows that fail to load and the reason for the failure.

```
CREATE TABLE test_agreements
AS SELECT * FROM agreements
WHERE ROWNUM <1;

INSERT INTO test_agreements
SELECT * 
    FROM agreements
LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
```

This will create you an error logging table called ERR$TEST_AGREEMENTS which you can query to find the problem rows.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work for this type of error but the OP should try and tell us i this helps  so +1

Comment: It's a table with so many rows that I can't do it. Furthermore it's not a database that I can edit in such a way so I can't even test it...but thanks for help and solution, +1.

Comment: @mleko - that's a shame this has worked for me in a similar situation with a view.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `WHERE key = 1` cause `key` is a [Reserve Word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle. You should escape it like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "key" = 1;
```

Comment: It was just an example. Query looks different and it's good for 100%(working with other keys).

Answer (score 0):

`KEY` is a reserved word so to overcome that you need to use double quotes `""`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "key" = 1;
```

Comment: It was just an example. Query looks different and it's good for 100%(working with other keys).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solved by putting the argument in quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM agreements WHERE agreementkey = "1";
```

I wish I were familiar with XML, but I have run into this with VARCHAR2 columns that are supposed to have all numeric values. Oracle looks at the request

```
where agreementkey = 1
```

and tries to convert agreementkey to a number rather than 1 to a varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

If the database contains invalid characters I would try one the following:

1. Maybe [the solution of BriteSponge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42141481/754550) will work, using an insert statemant with error logging clause.
2. Use datapump to export the data to a file. I think the log will contain information to identify the invalid columns.
3. There was a tool called "character set scanner" that checked the characters of the data of a table, here is some documentation: [CSSCAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DUMAG/ch1_overview.htm#DUMAG106). Or maybe you can use the Database Migration Assistent for Unicode (DMU) mentioned in the same manual.
   4- You can write a small PL/SQL program that retrieves the rows row by row and in case of an error catches the exception and notifies you about the row.

```
DECLARE
  invalid_character_detected EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_character_detected, ???);    begin
for SELECT rowid into rec FROM agreements do begin
    for 
        SELECT * into dummy 
            FROM agreements 
            where rowid=rec.rowid 
        do 
        null; 
        end loop;
    except
        WHEN invalid_character_detected THEN
            dbms_ouput.put_line(rec.rowid)
        end;
    end loop;
end;
```

I did not compile and test the program. ??? is the (negative) error code, e.g. -XXXXX if the error is ORA-XXXXX

Comment: Thanks, I will try maybe datadump. I know which rows are affected(I ran simple select queries).

Comment: @mleko I think I did not understand your problem. I thought you wanted to identifiy the rows that contain bad values? The posted solutios try to identify these columns. Export cannot retrieve zhe invalid characters.

Comment: Ah okay. So my problem is to somehow select those affected rows so that I can try to fix invalid data. Can you help with this? Is it possible? Now I can't select those rows and see what's wrong...It's not needed to identify invalid character - I just need to somehow export to file or console these rows.

Comment: What is the exact error message, the oracle db version and the datatype of the problem column?

Comment: Oracle db version is 12.1.0.2.0. Datatype of column is XMLTYPE. Error message I see is "Invalid character encountered in...".

Comment: is it "SQLException: Invalid character encountered in: failAL32UTF8Conv..."

Comment: maybe you should try to export at lleast one of the problem rows  with datapump (expdp) . if this works without error  then your problem is your client and not the data in the database.

Comment: Please post your NLS settings `SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS 
WHERE parameter IN
 ('NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_LANGUAGE','NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET','NLS_TERRITORY')`

Comment: I've tried expdp command, waiting for results. Will let you know if this works. Thanks!

Comment: Expdp succesful. When I'm trying to import it to my local db using impdp the job is successful but no new rows in table...

Comment: how many rows are exported and imported according to the logs?

Comment: Two rows exported, I used a query parameter to retrieve only wrong rows. But after import they are not present in DB so I still can't view content of this XMLType column.